# Are instructions for over-the-counter drugs legally binding?

Tags: united-states, medical, ohio

While it is a crime to use certain drugs or to use prescription drugs in a way not prescribed by your doctor, what about over-the-counter drugs? If, for example, the instructions of an over-the-counter drug say you should take it once every six hours, but due to circumstances on a certain day, you decide to take it an hour early (five hours), would you have committed a crime?

(If the answer varies by state, we can use Ohio's jurisdiction.)

Comment: When you say “legally binding” in what context do you mean? Let’s say someone dies from improperly taking drugs, do you mean the manufacturer would be held liable for misuse? Or the person themselves would be considered negligent for their own death?

Comment: @Giacomo1968 The question asks if one commits a crime by disobeying the instructions, so in using the term "legally binding," I ask whether it would be illegal to disobey such instructions.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In Ohio, it is not actually a crime to not follow the instructions for a prescription drug. The relevant prohibitions are in [ORC Chapter 2925](https://codes.ohio.gov/ohio-revised-code/chapter-2925), where [§2925.11](https://codes.ohio.gov/ohio-revised-code/section-2925.11) prohibits possession of certain substances under certain conditions. "Controlled substances" are determined via the CSA schedules down to [Schedule V](https://www.deadiversion.usdoj.gov/schedules/orangebook/c_cs_alpha.pdf), covering some but not all prescription drugs (e.g. not statins). The prohibition is stated as a blanket prohibition against any who "knowingly obtain, possess, or use a controlled substance or a controlled substance analog", followed by a list of exceptions such as pharmacist or manufacturer, and finally

> (d) Any person who obtained the controlled substance pursuant to a
> prescription issued by a licensed health professional authorized to
> prescribe drugs if the prescription was issued for a legitimate
> medical purpose and not altered, forged, or obtained through deception
> or commission of a theft offense.

Nothing demands that you follow the pharmacist instructions. However, there are certainly scenarios where you are not following instructions (triple dose of codeine to feed the habit, prescription issued in response to a patient's deceptive medical claims), where possession of the substance would then be illegal.

Apart from that, there is no criminal penalty attached to not "taking on an empty stomach" either for prescription drugs or OTC drugs.

Comment: You think it can be illegal to take triple the label dose of your legally prescribed pain killer? I don't think so.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica It is often illegal to attempt suicide, so there's that.

Answer (score 5):

> While it is a crime to use certain drugs or to use prescription drugs
> in a way not prescribed by your doctor, what about over-the-counter
> drugs?

Most (but not all) prescription drugs are controlled substances. Controlled substances that are not Schedule I controlled substances under the federal controlled substances act may be prescribed by a doctor in accordance with state regulated medical standards (including prescriptions for "off label" uses of a prescription drug contrary to its FDA authorized uses).

Also, most, but not all, states have controlled substances laws that track the federal controlled substances laws closely, although not necessarily exactly. A state can decline to treat a federally controlled substance as a controlled substance for state law purposes, and can likewise decide to classify a drug as a controlled substance for state law purposes even though federal law does not do so. A state can also define controlled substances offenses differently.

But all of these deviations from the federal controlled substances act tend to be rare exceptions in state statutes that track the federal law with only a handful of exceptions and with whatever modifications are necessary to fit into the state's classification of different grades of felony and misdemeanor offenses.

Using a prescription drug prescribed for someone else (or possessing a prescription drug prescribed for someone else for use by someone other than the person for whom it is prescribed) without a prescription is a controlled substances crime, although mere possession of a prescription drug prescribed for someone else in order to make the prescribed drug available to the person for whom it is prescribed would generally not be.

Arguably, it is a controlled substances crime to use a prescription drug for a condition other than the one for which it is prescribed after the condition for which it is prescribed ceases in cases where the prescribed condition does not recur.

For example, if you are prescribed codeine (a weak opiate) for a severe cough, and after the cough has ended while you are healthy, you use the prescribed codeine for recreational use, that *might* be a controlled substance offense. (I'm not an expert and haven't researched that question now since it is only tangential to the question asked.)

But simply using a drug prescribed for you in a manner other than the exact manner it is prescribed to be used to treat the condition for which the drug is prescribed is not a controlled substances offense.

> If, for example, the instructions of an over-the-counter drug say you
> should take it once every six hours, but due to circumstances on a
> certain day, you decide to take it an hour early (five hours), would
> you have committed a crime?

No. It is not a crime.

But, using an over-the-counter drug contrary to the instructions on its use is not entirely without legal consequences.

If you use an over-the-counter drug in a manner contrary to the instruction on its use and suffer injury or illness as a result of doing so, the manufacturer and seller of the over-the-counter drug can use this fact as a defense to a product liability lawsuit from the person who used the over-the-counter drug improperly and suffered ill effects as a result.

Comment: I think I see. While you wouldn't be committing a crime by taking an over-the-counter drug within five hours (as opposed to the label's instructions to take it within six hours), you would lose the ability to sue in the event that something goes wrong. Is this correct?

Comment: Note that "controlled substances" generally is used to refer to class IV and higher (which means lower numbers) stuff--things that have addictive or abuse potential.  An awful lot of prescription stuff is class V--stuff nobody would be interested in for non-medical purposes.

Comment: "Most (but not all) prescription drugs are controlled substances"—citation needed. Certainly there are a heck of a lot of controlled substances dispensed, but none of the [top 10 most prescribed drugs in the US](https://www.visualcapitalist.com/ranked-the-most-prescribed-drugs-in-the-u-s/) are controlled substances.

Comment: @ZachLipton Obviously, in this case, "most" is not an exact reference to a true majority. The point is that a lot are and some aren't.